# Is Light-4j similar to the AOP programming?

Tags: light-4j

While reading the Light-4j document, it looks like Light-4j is very similar to the AOP programming. What is the relationship between Light-4j and AOP programming?

Answer (score 0):

Light-4j is a subset of AOP programming that is leveraging the nature of the request/response flow of the HTTP based application. If we look at the request/response flow as chain, Light-4j put all the AOP cross-cutting concerns into the chain transparently to the developers. All cross-cutting concerns are implemented as middleware handlers, and they can be enabled or disabled with individual config files or a centralized values.yml file. With externalized config files, we can move a dockerized application from one environment to another with only config changes. Another benefit of this design is to increase the productivity of developers. Unlike other frameworks, developers have to wire in the cross-cutting concerns manually with code or annotations, Light-4j wire in the cross-cutting concerns with configuration files, and these can be applied by the operation team instead of the development team. This allows developers to focus on the business logic at the endpoint level without thinking about metrics, tracing, monitoring, alerting, etc.